# What would be pseudo code or logic for the below question? The ultimate approach is to find a Dynamic Programming Solution

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, recurrence

Let P[1 · · m], and Q[1 · · n] be two point sequences on the plane. Imagine two frogs Pfrog and Qfrog that are connected to each other with a rope would like to traverse these sequences together. In the beginning Pfrog is at P[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iOIj.png), and Qfrog is at Q[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iOIj.png). At each step, if the Pfrog is at P[i] and Qfrog is at Q[j], they can proceed in three different ways: (A) Pfrog jumps forward to P[i + 1], and Qfrog stays at Q[j], (B) Qfrog jumps forward to Q[j + 1], and Pfrog stays at P[i], or (C) Pfrog and Qfrog jump forward together to P[i + 1] and Q[j + 1], respectively. (Note the frogs can never jump backwards.) Consider a piece of rope with length L. We say this piece of rope is useful, if there is some traversal of P and Q such that Pfrog and Qfrog are always ≤ L apart. You job is to determine the smallest useful integer rope length. (Since longer ropes cost more money.)

[image: Figure 1]

Figure 1: A valid sequence of moves for Pfrog and Qfrog is (P[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iOIj.png), Q[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iOIj.png)) → (P[2], Q[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iOIj.png)) → (P[3], Q[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iOIj.png)) → (P[4], Q[2]) → (P[5], Q[3]) → (P[5], Q[4]) → (P[5], Q[5]) → (P[5], Q[6]).

Comment: You might get more engagement if you included what you've tried so far, so it doesn't look like you're asking for code.

Answer (score 0):

A naive recurrence need only consider the previous possible states of `O(|P| * |Q|)` states:

```
f(1, 1) ->
  dist(P[1], Q[1]);
  
f(1, j) ->
  max(f(1, j-1), dist(P[1], Q[j]));
  
f(i, 1) ->
  max(f(i-1, 1), dist(P[i], Q[1]));
  
f(i, j) ->
  max(
    dist(P[i], Q[j]),
    min(
      f(i-1, j-1),
      f(i, j-1),
      f(i-1, j)
    )
  ).
```